# Display a dynamic drop down list in alfresco advanced share search

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

I have a set of documents in a folder in the alfresco share site. Each folder represents a category of document. I would like to display all the contents of the folder as a drop-down list in advanced search for the users to select from, when they select a particular category.
I understand that I could retrieve the document names in the folder by javascript or java. I am confused as how to integrate it with the advanced search.

What would be the right approach to start with ?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say Java CMIS what do you mean? CMIS is an interoperability standard and Alfresco Share already understands the Alfresco repository data model. What have you tried as far as modifying the Share UI?

Comment: Hi @Mardoz, I am using CMIS queries from a Java client program to retrieve the file names. I would like to display these names in an advanced search drop-down menu in share.

Comment: Do you mean the advanced search in Share? or a custom advanced search?

Comment: Whichever would be suitable for the task.

Comment: Mentioning CMIS in the question is confusing the issue. I'm pretty sure what you are doing from your Java client via CMIS is not relevant to what you are trying to do. It sounds like you are trying to modify the Alfresco Share Advanced Search page so that when someone selects a category you dynamically populate a dropdown list with the names of the files in that category. If so can you re-word your question to that effect?